# How to configure OSD container for CEHP

Tags: linux, docker, ceph

I'm trying to setup CEPH cluster with docker containers, however I can't run container for OSD. I ran monitor container with following command:

```
docker run -d --net=host --name MON -v /etc/ceph:/etc/ceph -v /var/lib/ceph/:/var/lib/ceph -e MON_IP=1.1.1.1 -e CEPH_PUBLIC_NETWORK=1.1.1.0/24 ceph/daemon mon
```

Then to run OSD I use:

```
docker run -d --net=host --name OSD --privileged=true -v /etc/ceph:/etc/ceph -v /var/lib/ceph/:/var/lib/ceph -v /dev/:/dev/ -e OSD_DEVICE=/dev/sdc ceph/daemon osd_ceph_disk
```

but it fails with following logs:

```
2019-05-10 13:28:59  /opt/ceph-container/bin/entrypoint.sh: static: does not generate config
Error: /dev/sdc: unrecognised disk label
2019-05-10 13:28:59  /opt/ceph-container/bin/entrypoint.sh: Device detected, assuming ceph-disk scenario is desired
2019-05-10 13:28:59  /opt/ceph-container/bin/entrypoint.sh: Preparing and activating /dev/sdc
HEALTH_WARN 1 osds down; 1 host (1 osds) down; 1 root (1 osds) down; no active mgr
Error: /dev/sdc: unrecognised disk label
/opt/ceph-container/bin/osd_disk_prepare.sh: line 46: ceph-disk: command not found
```

I'm running both monitor and osd on the same device and I'm sure that `/dev/sdc` exist on host. I have docker `1.12.6, build 5680db5/1.12.6` version.

`ceph -s` output from monitor:

```
    id:     5bf42838-97f0-492b-81ac-58c7c39a56b3
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            1 osds down
            1 host (1 osds) down
            1 root (1 osds) down
            no active mgr
            mon localhost is low on available space

  services:
    mon:        1 daemons, quorum localhost (age 3d)
    mgr:        no daemons active (since 4d)
    mds:        cephfs:1 {0=demo=up:active(laggy or crashed)}
    osd:        2 osds: 0 up (since 4d), 1 in (since 5d)
    rbd-mirror: 1 daemon active (4137)
    rgw:        1 daemon active (localhost)

  data:
    pools:   8 pools, 64 pgs
    objects: 250 objects, 5.3 KiB
    usage:   1.0 GiB used, 9.0 GiB / 10 GiB avail
    pgs:     64 active+clean
```

The final goal I want to achieve is minimal docker ceph cluser with block device used for storage.

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer is not going to solve your question, but why don't you use rook [1]? Rook works perfectly with k8s [2] and was already accepted in the Cloud Native Computing Foundation incubating project, has an awesome community on slack [3].

You should try it.

[1] https://rook.io/ 
[2] https://rook.io/docs/rook/master/ceph-quickstart.html 
[3] https://slack.rook.io/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in virtual box, create a new disk like shown in the image. After logining in to operating system, find the disk name under /dev directory and give the path on the docker command

[image]